# Where is composer.phar in zend framework 2.5

Tags: zend-framework2

I have clone zf2.5 via git, and I create project via composer, but both comes without composer.phar. Only composer.json and composer.lock.

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [zf2 github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2), you will see there is no composer.phar in git.

If you want to install zf2 via composer, you have to install composer [locally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally) or [globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally).

And then run in your directory `php composer.phar require zendframework/zendframework` or `composer require zendframework/zendframework`.